# I have a aspx(vb) website. When I try to remove .vb files (leaving .aspx ones there) it always gets HttpParseException?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

question as the title says, my website is under .Net 4.0. And my project is an ASP.Net Web Application in VS2010. I'm sure that the website dll is compiled into the /Bin folder and it do include the required classes for my .aspx files.

a sample of my .aspx file is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/main.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

and the related .vb file is:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits BasePage

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPreInit(e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.ModuleID = 2
        MyBase.OnPreInit(e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

and in myproject.dll it do have the class "_Default". When I try to visit my site it throws the exception that

```
System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): The file '/Default.aspx.vb' does not exist.
```

Is it related to VB.net? Because I remember that my last project is under aspx+C# and it works fine if I removed all the .cs files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with VB.Net...your Page directive `CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb"` is the "issue" (not really, but if you delete the *codefile* then it becomes one).

For ASP.net Web Applications, [its `CodeBehind=...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/015103yb(v=vs.100).aspx)

MSDN:

> ...the attribute that identifies the code-behind *file* is CodeFile. In a Web application project, the attribute is named CodeBehind...

Hth...

Comment: when I delete the CodeFile="Default.aspx" (or replace it with CodeBehind) it always says that "Could not load type _Default"?

Comment: It's because of designer class and aspx are not compatible...!

Comment: @biz.tim Go through the linked document - and read up on the differences between a "web site" and "web application", and `publish` -> (pre) complile options.